# Accessing WCF Services Callbacks from Non Microsoft Clients

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, language-interoperability, wcf-callbacks

WCF is supposed to be interoperable, WCF services can be accessed from microsoft & non-microsoft clients, but only Microsoft clients can access WCF callback services.
The question is: Is it possible for non-microsoft clients to access WCF callback services?
Is there any way to have an active bidirectional channel between microsoft service and non microsoft clients?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. There the first comment say: it's .net only. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/Q_26617678.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not just post links to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) but rather explain your answer in your post and add the link for further "in-depth" reading.